# input bar disappears after a couple of secounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

JS Fiddle link >> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9ax5/1/)

My problem is next:
As you can see on the code from jsfiddle, after i click on a button, input bar shows.
Problem is that on my website, after i click on a button, input shows and then disappears after a couple of secounds, and everything is back on like before i clicked it.(input is gone and i have a button to click on). So if i click again, entire thing goes around and around.

there is code as well:

```
  <input value="" name="s" id="s" type="text">
    <input id="searchsubmit" value="Search" type="submit">

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#searchsubmit').click(function(){
         $('#s').show();
     });
   });
```

and

```
    #s{display:none;}
```

is there a way to make this input not being hidden, and stay shown for at least 10 secounds?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks to me like you've already fixed your issue. Is your live page reloading when you click the button?

Comment: There must be something else in your javascript interfering, not mentioned in your OP. Your jsFiddle example seems to be working fine.

Comment: well jsfiddle is working. but on site not. ok thanks, but also another question, is there a way to make certain item to stay shown for like 10s?

Comment: @Milosh is the `<input>` surrounded by a `<form>` on your site?

Comment: @ Explosion Pills yes it is actually.

Comment: @Milosh is `#searchsubmit` a submit button?

Comment: @Archer yes it is and form id is searchform. i updated jsfiddle.

Comment: In that case, it shows because of `$('#s').show();` and then disappears when the page is reloaded, due to the submit button being clicked.

Comment: so what could be solution, to stop doing that? any minor changes into code?

Comment: Change the button to `type="button"` instead of submit :)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the page is reloading after your form submit.  That would reset your box to be visible again. Try catching the form submit event and do a preventDefault on it and see if the box is still hidden.